# Issue when trying to Register a Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientFactory.Instance to DbProviderFactories

Tags: .net, .net-6.0, sqlclient

I got the following line

```
DbProviderFactories.RegisterFactory("Microsoft.Data.SqlClient", Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientFactory.Instance);
```

in a .cs file inside a .NET 6.0 project which references Microsoft.Data.SqlClient package like so
[image]

When i get to that line of code in debug, Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientFactory.Instance is **null** and I don't know why.

I also tried to create a simple .NET 6.0 project that references the same package and only uses the same line of code and it works just fine.

**Note:**
I use the C# project in a CLR project and the CLR project in a C++ project. Maybe there is a reference issue / dll location issue

Answer (score 0):

In my case of WPF app, it required specific windows dependent references.

So I had to specifcy RID:

```
<PropertyGroup>
 <RuntimeIdentifier>win10-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Afterwards, **SqlClientFactory.Instance** was not null anymore